# How to View PDF attachments in Lightning Experience without downloading them

Tags: lightning, pdf, view, classic

I often need to quickly view PDFs attached to Accounts. In Classic, I can quickly View them. However, in Lightning Experience, I am only able to download them. Is there a way to view these attachments in Lightning Experience without downloading them every time? Thank you!

Classic (with View option):

[image]

Lightning Experience (no View option, only download)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup → Security → File Upload and Download Security, find the .pdf label, click the Edit button, and set the picklist value of the pdf to Execute In Browser.

Note that this is an org-wide setting. After this change, when a user goes to a PDF file download URL, the file will be displayed, instead of downloaded automatically.